# Elasticsearch Ngram Analyzer to Search Part Mac Addresses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, n-gram

Using ElasticSearch (and Rails) I'm trying unsuccessfully to index and perform search queries on a field containing mac addresses using hyphens as a delimiter:

> 24-A4-3C-02-37-26

All is well when searching the entire mac address (unindexed) but I cannot get a part match working using a custom analyzer.

I have tested with numerous options including adjusting the min / max vals with no success.

With the mappings, settings and queries below, I get the following results:

```
Box.search(q: "24-A4-3C-02-37-26").results.map(&:macaddress)
```

Which yields a weird result:

```
["24-A4-3C-02-37-xx", "DC-9F-DB-F6-B2-xx", "C4-10-8A-13-53-xx", "C4-10-8A-13-54-xx", "C4-10-8A-13-52-xx"]
```

If I run with the last octet removed ("24-A4-3C-02-37"), I get this:

```
["DC-9F-DB-F6-B2-xx", "C4-10-8A-13-53-xx", "C4-10-8A-13-52-xx"]
```

Which is wrong.

I've checked the analyzer using the API and it looks just swell:

```
curl "localhost:9205/boxes/_analyze?analyzer=ngram_analyzer&pretty=true" -d "24-A4-3C-02-37-26"
```

Which yields:

```
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "24",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 2,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "24-",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 3,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 2
  }, {
    "token" : "24-A",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 4,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 3
  }, {
  .........
```

So I can only guess that there's something with my actual query. I've even tried replacing the hyphens with ascii or escaping.

```
@search_definition[:query] = {
  multi_match: {
    query: options[:q],
    fields: [
      "macaddress.ngram",
      "macaddress.sortable^5",
        ...
```

My settings look like this:

```
settings analysis: {
  analyzer: {
    ngram_analyzer: {
      type: 'custom',
      tokenizer: 'my_tokenizer',
    }
  },
  tokenizer: {
    my_tokenizer: {
      type: "edgeNGram",
      min_gram: 2,
      max_gram: 17,
      # token_chars: [ "letter", "digit" ]
    }
  }
} do

  mapping do
    indexes :macaddress, type: 'multi_field', fields: {
      raw: { type: "string" },
      sortable: { type: "string", index: "not_analyzed" },
      ngram: { type: "string", index_analyzer: :ngram_analyzer } #, search_analyzer: 'keyword' }
    }
    end
end
```

Can someone suggest how I can get this to work?

Comment: Have you tried setting analyzer rather than index_analyzer (and rebuilding the index) or setting the analyzer when querying?

Comment: Yep, I have rebuilt numerous times. Using analyzer instead has no impact at all. I've added the analyzer to the query params but this which shows even fewer results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have verified with the following settings:

```
PUT test
    {
        "settings" : {
            "analysis" : {
                "analyzer" : {
                    "ngram_analyzer" : {
                        "type": "custom",
                        "tokenizer" : "my_tokenizer"
                    }
                },
                "tokenizer" : {
                    "my_tokenizer" : {
                        "type" : "edgeNGram",
                        "min_gram" : "2",
                        "max_gram" : "17"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "mappings": {
          "boxes":{
            "properties": {
              "macaddress":{
                "type": "multi_field",
                "fields": {
                  "raw":{
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "sortable":{
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                  },
                  "ngram":{
                    "type": "string",
                    "index_analyzer": "ngram_analyzer"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
    }
```

And some sample data:

```
PUT test/boxes/1
{
  "macaddress":"24-A4-3C-02-37-26"
}
PUT test/boxes/2
{
  "macaddress":"24-A4-3C-02-37-54"
}
PUT test/boxes/3
{
  "macaddress":"24-A4-3C-02-38-23"
}
PUT test/boxes/4
{
"macaddress":"34-A4-3C-02-38-23"
}
```

And the search query:

```
GET test/boxes/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "24-A4-3C-02",
      "fields": ["macaddress.ngram",
      "macaddress.sortable^5"]
    }
  }
}
```

The result is:

```
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 0.047079325,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "boxes",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.047079325,
            "_source": {
               "macaddress": "24-A4-3C-02-37-26"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "boxes",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.047079325,
            "_source": {
               "macaddress": "24-A4-3C-02-37-54"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "boxes",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 0.047079325,
            "_source": {
               "macaddress": "24-A4-3C-02-38-23"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: And the difference between the two? What ES version are you running, not that should matter?

Comment: It's ES 1.5, try to check with the same mapping using curl .

Comment: Turns out there was a description field that was being indexed and was polluting the index. And I had to adjust the search analyser slightly. Whilst your answer didn't directly resolve the issue, I think you deserve the bonus points :)

Comment: My solution was based on the index mapping that you have provided.

Comment: Yes, the same mapping. Which doesn't constitute an answer - replicating exactly what was in the question. Nevertheless, I have accepted your answer and will detail what needed to be done separately.